# How can I repair or replace this exterior door sweep?

Tags: doors, weatherstripping

I have an exterior door that always leaks water when it rains a certain way. I've done everything to fix it but nothing seems to work, and I can't find a good replacement for this weather-stripping. Anyone have any recommendations? Looks like there are two grooves, but can't find one to fit.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: A clear photo of the sweep when the door is closed might help, from inside and outside.   You should also observe the door during heavy rain to see if the water entering the house is trickling down the door and then rolling in, or is being driven in by wind along the threshhold.

Answer (score 3):

Your picture is of a door *sweep*.

Take the pic to your local hardware or big box store and they can help you match it.

Some just pull off, some have a few screws, some require the door be removed and the sweep is anchored to the door bottom.

No residential door is made to have a complete water seal. If rain is a usual problem you should look into covering the door with a roof to protect it from the rain.

Answer (score 0):

Is rain blowing in, not flooding in? Is your actual threshold higher than the ground/floor level just outside it? [It looks like there's a half inch but it's hard to tell in the out of focus area.]

If so, it just looks to me like your weather bar is too small & too high.

It should just skim the threshold & protrude a couple of inches or so. That ought to prevent the wind from blowing rain under, & be good enough to hold until the water level got high enough to literally flood.

You could think of the seal as a draught excluder, not as rain protection. Doors for centuries didn't have seals at the bottom - the weather bar did the job instead.

[image]